# Locally Compact Groups - Reference Request

Tags: functional-analysis, harmonic-analysis, banach-algebras

I start reading an article about locally compact groups $G$ and the group algebra $L^1(G)$,and  I need a good book to introduce myself to these concepts.

Can you help please?

Thanx

Comment: ["A Course in Abstract Harmonic Analysis"](http://books.google.ca/books?id=0VwYZI1DypUC&pg=PP3&lpg=PP3&dq=folland+abstract+harmonic+analysis&source=bl&ots=cuT_w33cyP&sig=goBqNpdSUg8-eAIlbwp11NiMcbk&hl=en&sa=X&ei=w68oVMWmMaHViwKQ1ICIDA&ved=0CC4Q6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=folland%20abstract%20harmonic%20analysis&f=false) by Folland is good.

Comment: I haven't looked very much at ["Abstract Harmonic Analysis : Vol 1"](http://books.google.ca/books/about/Abstract_Harmonic_Analysis.html?id=uf11K1wXEYUC&redir_esc=y) and ["Abstract Harmonic Analyis: Vol 2"](http://books.google.ca/books/about/Abstract_Harmonic_Analysis.html?id=r57SsikRFPAC) by Hewitt and Ross, but, given the authors, I would expect them to be very polished, and to contain a massive amount of material.